# Why is readf not returning a value?

Tags: d, dmd

According to the [documentation](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_stdio.html#readf), `readf` is supposed to return a `uint`.  But even this simple example fails to compile:

*hello.d*

```
import std.stdio;

void main() {
    int x;
    uint r = readf("%s", &x);    
}
```

error message:

```
hello.d(5): Error: expression readf("%s",& x) is void and has no value
```

Am I missing something here?

I'm using dmd (Digital Mars D) compiler v2.050.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing [a new version of DMD](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/changelog.html#new2_052). This bug was fixed (silently) in v2.052 (at commit [86a080f](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/commit/86a080f0564060dd85110d5337c96686d6bdf8b3#diff-3)).